# _isUrlInternal function issue with multiwebsite magento 2

Tags: magento2

I am getting the issue with the redirection with multi-website.
I am on multiwebsite and I am trying to redirect the URL from admin using the above code
return $this->_redirect($this->_redirect->getRefererUrl());

_isUrlInternal function is creating the issue with that.
As in my code, store is changed and due to that _isUrlInternal  is always redirecting me to second website home page due to _isUrlInternal  function condition.

Can't we modify the _isUrlInternal  function definition so that it can understand the admin URL as well?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, i found a solution for the same by setting up the store manager to admin.
The code that I used before redirection was : 
 $this->_storeModelStoreManagerInterface->setCurrentStore(0);